# Make column as required in html

Tags: html, css

I have a column like below.

```html
 <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: bottom;" class="BorderOnly">
           -- a canvas sign input
</td>
```

is it possible to make this td as required field?

Comment: What “field” are you talking about? Properly explain what “a canvas sign input” is supposed to be in the first place.

Comment: You can always make an input required `<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>`

Answer (score 1):

instead of `<td>` you can add the `required` prop to the input field like this.

`<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>`